# window.opener not working in IE8-9

Tags: javascript, window.opener, showmodaldialog

I followed this article [Pass value from child window to parent window](http://hspinfo.wordpress.com/2008/01/17/javascript-send-pass-value-of-child-window-to-parent-window/).

It is working perfect in Firefox and chrome, but gives error in IE8 and IE9.

To open the child page I am using:

```
window.showModalDialog('child.html','','width=550,height=170,left=150,top=200,toolbar=1,status=1,scrollbars=yes');
```

It gives me following error:

[image: Script Error]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
window.showModalDialog(child.html,'','unadorned:yes;resizable:1;
dialogHeight:170px;dialogwidth:550px;scroll:yes;status=yes');
```